A jupyter notebook, hosted on GitHub and running in Google Colab, gives file not found error for existing files
I am running a jupyter notebook, directly from the GitHub repository of yhilpisch, on Google Colab. The notebook has a cell %run xxx.py, which is in the same directory as the notebook in the repo, and I get a file not found error. Another cell attempts to load a csv file in a data directory in the repo, with an appropriate path, but also file not found error. Is it possible for such a notebook to access these files, and if so what additional steps do I need to take to make it happen?
Ran the cells, expected no errors.

Colab allows one to choose Github as the source to open a notebook, after specifying the Github user and selecting from that users repos. However loading data files is problematic. If I clone the repo to my Google Drive I can run the notebook and load the files in the usual way. Just wondering what's the point of opening directly from Github, as most notebooks do load data (in my experience)

I remember where I tried this recently in answering this SO post where the OP was smartly trying to move from using Colab to actual Jupyter. That way described at the involved repo github.com/BigDFT-group/bigdft-school, I believe is what you are describing? Along the lines of where it says there for  Step #2 under 'To do that:' "File-> Open Notebook - > GitHub` (Although the interface seems a little different not to me but that is the gist of the pathway.) When I do those steps, and choose ...

  the notebook CCP_tutorials/0.Installation.ipynb from the list. In the session that comes up, I do see a directory sample_data with some generic machine learning associated files in it listed if I toggle to the folder icon to the left or if I run ls.  Google Gemini says that may be "Colab's built-in dataset integration: Colab often provides pre-loaded datasets" that comes in sample_data. Importantly, I do note that the rest of that particular notebook is about setting up the environment in Colab and getting data and so I think it doesn't come with an environment & data.

I appreciate your taking time to help me with this. For me it's basically a management issue. I'm studying a lot, with a lot of code from several books and online courses, and I am interested to see if I can run through that code without having to 'clutter up' my local machine with yet another project. Previously I have bee downloading the repos and running jupyter notebook locally. However I'm trying to become more familiar with 'cloud based' solutions, and hoped to find a way to get this run on github approach to work. I'll stick with running locally henceforth.

MyBinder and Anaconda Cloud are very suitable for exactly what you just described. To make this clear nothing that you have described involves running in an "run on github approach", as you call it. You are getting resources from GitHub and running on virtual machines provided by elsewhere. GitHub does now offer computational resources directly. GitHub's Codespaces is that. And they can even run Jupyter, see here and so it is important to keep the language clear.

 I should add you'll want to give yourself time at the outset to learn what works and is best for you. It's okay to stumble around trying some things. Doing that in the cloud is easier and gives less chance of messing up your system, and so it is probably worth investing the time to learn some of it. I should have added that Anaconda Cloud requires time learning about Anaconda/conda's management ways. Also, could you please delete the phrase "gives file not found error for existing files" from your title. I think you found those don't exist where you are actually working, correct?

(I'm putting this here because I deleted a lot of my early questions and discussions otherwise.)I suggested using MyBinder.org from the Jupyter Community folks so you get real Jupyter with the entire repo cloned along with it. You just have to be a little more patient and understand it is a temporary session so you should immediately save anything useful you make by downloading it to your local machine. And then you'd be ready to start in a new session later. Here is an example repo. ...

  If you go there and click the launch binder badge you get a temporary session with everything there. Plus MyBinder uses the requirements.txt there to make the environment already set up with the specified packages so that everything works. (I realized that one opens in the classic interface. Try here and here for more modern JupyterLab at start up. The latter one is a good example that you can make thing environment quite complex and it will work.) ...

  Go here for more of an overview of MyBinder use. Plus I should add it works fine with GitHub's gists if making a repo is overwhelming at this point. This one I forked from another gist and edited directly in the browser to edit requirements.txt and runtime.txt to be what I needed for here. I didn't bother here, but I could combine those things...

 to be more convenient by taking advantage of nbgitpuller to pull in the notebook and other content from that other gist to sessions launched from the first gist. I have a simple example that will come up if you ...

 click here. You'll see just before the notebook comes up, a blue bar shows that the active session is using nbgitpuller to grab the notebook from a gist and then open it. If it had other documents in the gist or repo they would come, too!!.

I have found an answer to my initial question, and that is to access data files by  providing a URL, say data = pd.read_csv('<url of csv file>'). Whether using this approach (run notebooks hosted on GitHub using Google Colab) is a good idea, see the detailed discussion provided by Wayne.
